# DB Design - Sending JSON to REST API which persists the data in MySQL database

Tags: json, rest, database-design, data-modeling, api-design

So this is more of a conceptual question. There might be some fundamental concepts which I don't understand clearly so please point out any mistakes in my understanding.

I am tasked with designing a framework and a part of it is  I have a MySQL DB and a REST API which acts as the Data Access Layer. Now, the user should be able to parse various data (JSON, CSV, XML, Text, Source Code etc.) and send it to the REST API which persists the data to the DB.

**Question 1**: Should I specify that all data sent to the REST API should be in JSON format no matter what is parsed? This will ensure (best to my understanding) language independence and gives the REST API a common format to deal with.

**Question 2**: When it comes to a data model, what should I specify? Is it like a one-model-fits-all sort of thing or is the data model subject to change based on the incoming data?

**Question 3**: When I think of a relational data model, the thought of foreign keys comes to mind which creates the *relation*. Now, it might happen that some data may not contain any relation at all. If we think of something like `Customer` `Order` sort of data then the relation is easy to identify. But what if the data does not have any relation at all? How does the relational model fit into this?

Any help/suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:

First off, the data can be both structured (say XML) and unstructured (say two text files). I want the DAL to be able to handle and persist whatever data that comes in (that's why I thought of a REST interface in front of the DB).

Secondly, I also just recently thought about MongoDB as an option and was looking into it (I have never used NoSQL DBs before). It kind of makes sense to use it if the incoming data in REST is in JSON. From what I understood I can create a collection in Mongo. Does that make more sense than using a Relational DB??

Finally, as to what I want to do with the data is I have a tool which performs a sort of difference analysis (think `git diff`) on the data. Say I sent two XML files and the tool retrieves it from the DB and performs the difference analysis and stores the result back in the DB.

Based on these requirements, what would be the optimum way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this will depend on what sort of data it is. Are all these different data types using different notation for the same data? If so then storing in normalised database tables is the way to go. If its just arbitrary strings that happen to have some form of encoding, then its probably best to store in raw.

Again, it depends on what you want to do with it afterwards. Are you analysing the data, and you reporting on it? Are you reading one format and converting to another? Is it all some form of key-value pairs in some notation or other

No way to answer this further without understanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I edited the question and added the clarifications. Also ended up asking another question!